# Libraries(armel) for cross compiling

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling

Where can I get compiled libraries specific architectures?  My company hired some contractors to port some code to our powerpc platform.  I am trying to move this to an arm platform(omap3).

They created a cross compiling environment(in Windows).  All of the libraries that are linked at still compiled for PowerPC.   For each lib there are 3 files: .so, .so.X and .so.X.Y.Z  I can get the second 2 from the deb packages and I found the .so in developer deb package but it is 0 bytes.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in [Angstrom](http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/)?

Comment: THe Angstron ipkg were the same as the deb packages.  The dev versions have a .la file and a empty .so file.  Does something happen when you install the packages?

Comment: Uh wait. You're missing just the .so (with no version suffix) file? That's just a symlink to the other. libsomething.so is link to libsomething.so.major which is a link to libsomething.so.major.minor.evenmoreminor.

Comment: It looks like all of the powerpc libs are the same size.
libxml2.so        3.39MB
libxml2.so.2      3.39MB
libxml2.so.2.6.7  3.39MB  are they all just the same file named differently?

Comment: There should be one file... libxml2.so.2.6.7. The other two should be symbolinc links to this one. Why do you call them powerpc libs and say you're looking for arm binaries?

Comment: The libs that I have now are Powerpc ones.  I am trying to port the code to arm  and I need to replace them.

We are using an eclipse setup in windows(codesoucrey cross compiler).  The current(PowerPC libs.so,.so.x etc) are just located in a separate folder.  How does this symbolic link work under this scenrio?

Thanks,

Comment: Hmm check this then: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Answer (score 0):

Theres no way (that I know of) to convert a binary from machine A(power pc) into binaries for machine B(arm). If you have the source, or a way of acquiring the source, you can rebuild them for your arm target.  You can accomplish this by either using a local compiler on a arm machine, or cross compile using a cross compiling tool chain (eg code sorcery lite (http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/lite/arm) to build libraries from your build machine onto your arm target.  Most libraries are not obtainable on arm in a pre-compiled form.
Depending on what OS you're using on your arm target, eg debian or redhat.  There may be a package manager available to do this for you.